# Customizing Hibernate Criteria - Adding conditions to a left join

Tags: hibernate, join, criteria

I need to be able to do the following:

Select * from Table1
   left join Table2 on id1 = id2 AND i1 = ?

Hibernate criteria doesn't allow be to specify the i1 = ? part.

The existing code is using hibernate criteria and it would be a huge refactor to swap out for HQL

Does anybody have any tips how I could implement this differently or any way to override the Hibernate Criteria? I'm not opposed to cracking open hibernate and modifying, but when I began to dig it, there seems to be layers upon layers of abstractions. I never found the the point where SQL is actually generated...

Answer (score 13):

This appears to be what I need...

http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2308

i.e.

```
public Criteria createAlias(String associationPath, String alias, int joinType, Criterion withClause) throws HibernateException;

public Criteria createCriteria(String associationPath, String alias, int joinType, Criterion withClause) throws HibernateException;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Fetch mode to Join. You can do it by doing this:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Table1.class);
criteria.setFetchMode(table2OutputList, FetchMode, JOIN);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("i1", i1Value);
return criteria.list();
```

In this case, you will have to fetch the table2OutputList before running this query. This [article](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Java/Hibernate-Criteria-Queries-in-Depth/2/) can give you a better idea;

Comment: Wouldn't that just create this:

SELECT * from Table1 
  left join Table2 on id1 = id2
WHERE i1 = ?

I don't want i1 = ? in my where on want it as part of the "ON" expression..